# logrotate not rotates my logs

Tags: centos, logging, logrotate

My logrotate works perfectly, except for this configuration:

```
/var/awdata/awarchive.*.log 
/var/log/awstats.log 
{
        rotate 12
}
```

This is my `logrotate -d /etc/logorate.conf` output:

```
considering log /var/awdata/awarchive.domain1.it.log
   log needs rotating
```

and then:

```
rotating log /var/awdata/awarchive.domain1.it.log, log->rotateCount is 4
dateext suffix '-20120517'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
fscreate context set to unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0
renaming /var/awdata/awarchive.domain1.it.log to /var/awdata/awarchive.domain1.it.log-20120517
creating new /var/awdata/awarchive.domain1.it.log mode = 0666 uid = 99 gid = 501
```

logrotate seems to work perfectly, but it does not do what I wrote. :-(

==

```
ls -lah /var/awdata/*domain1*
```

About domain1:

```
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 nobody nogroup 4.7G May 17 17:16 /var/awdata/awarchive.domain1.it.log
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 nobody nogroup 7.6G May  9 04:16 /var/awdata/awarchive.domain1.it.log-20120509
```

The only rotate log *-20120509 was forced with the `-f` option.

```
[root@lnx1 awdata]# ls -ld /var/awdata
drwxr-xr-x. 2 nobody nogroup 188416 May 17 18:52 /var/awdata
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide the output of `ls -lah /var/awdata/` so we can see what actually was rotated?

Comment: -d     Turns on debug mode and implies -v.  In debug mode, no changes will be made to the logs or to the logrotate state file.

Comment: Be careful, if you do not have space in filesystem, it won't be rotated, this is my experience.

Comment: Is /var/awdata writable for logrrotate? It wants create the files with uid 99 gid 501 while the existing files' owner is nobody/nogroup. Maybe you need to chmod /var/awdata to 1777 mode? Show `ls -ld /var/awdara`.

Comment: i've got space enough :-) 
now, i force rotation (-f) and works perfectly... :-(

Comment: drwxr-xr-x. 2 nobody nogroup  /var/awdata

Comment: Sometimes, I have to use force (-f), and rotation works for the logfile in question henceforth.  Check again tomorrow?

Comment: check again next week by now... :-(

Answer (score 2):

Note that `logrotate -d` turns on “debug” mode, where logrotate reports what it *would* do if the `-d` flag was not present.

Try using `logrotate -v`, which *applies* the actions it describes, then come back with any further issues.